# Text Messaging Android Application

Tags: android, sms, wear-os, smart-device

How do smart watches receive text messages from mobile phone? I am looking to make a similar application and I am not sure where to start. I want to make an application for my tablet that will show text message notification.

Answer (score 1):

To create a notification that is transmitted to connected Android Wear devices, you need to use the NotificationCompat class located in the Support v4-Package.
The detailed documentation how to do this can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html).

The code essentially breaks down to this code snippet (copied from the documentation):

```
int notificationId = 001;
// Build intent for notification content
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, ViewEventActivity.class);
viewIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_EVENT_ID, eventId);
PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event)
        .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
        .setContentText(eventLocation)
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

// Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

This creates a notification on the handheld as well as connected Android Wear devices, without even creating a Wear-App. The pairing and transmitting process is handled by the OS.

As a general hint, the Training section of Android Developers is always a good place to start researching.

Comment: I have not had any luck implementing NotificationCompat.Builder successfully. Are you familiar with Bluetooth profiles? I have been reading about MAP (message access profile) it allows the exchange of messages between devices. Wondering if I could go this route?

Comment: Can be describe your problems in more details? The precondition for this approach is, that you have connected your Smartwatch to your phone using the Android Wear app. I haven't used any Low-Level Bluetooth services on Android. If you want to transfer more complex data than only notifications, you should use the Google Services though, to ensure compatibility over multiple devices, see http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html